# Handling time ranges in Java

Tags: java

I have a variable `Date someDate = new Date(0)` that starts at the Unix Epoch and is incremented. I need to test whether the *time* of `someDate` is currently between 0000 and 1200 hours. Essentially I need to be able to compare a `Date` object with a time range.

Is there a way to do this in Java, or do I need to roll my own or use something like Joda-Time?

Comment: what is wrong with `long`?

Comment: How do you increment `someDate`?

Comment: This is for a simulation, so `someDate` is not incremented in real time. A timer waits a set interval and then adds some other number of seconds to `someDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). See this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(someDate);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour < 12) {
    // 0 <= hour < 12
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not as elegant as I was hoping for, but easier than dragging in another library.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use Joda time, but if you just want to compare dates, you could just use the `compareTo` method from the `Date` java class, [javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

Comment: I don't want to compare dates, only the time of day.